# Can't install Bioperl Module (properly?)

Tags: bioperl, cpanm

I am not able to install a BioPerl Module via cpanm. With

```
sudo cpanm Bio::SeqIO
```

The output says:

```
--> Working on Bio::SeqIO
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/C/CJ/CJFIELDS/BioPerl-1.6.922.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring BioPerl-1.006922 ... OK
Building and testing BioPerl-1.006922 ... FAIL
! Installing Bio::SeqIO failed. See /home/administrator/.cpanm/work/1398677477.16274/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

When adding --force it says:

```
--> Working on Bio::SeqIO
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/C/CJ/CJFIELDS/BioPerl-1.6.922.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring BioPerl-1.006922 ... OK
Building and testing BioPerl-1.006922 ... FAIL
! Testing BioPerl-1.006922 failed but installing it anyway.
Successfully installed BioPerl-1.006922
1 distribution installed
```

So I am not sure whether I can use BioPerl now properly? Can I simply ignore that the testing failed?
I have already tried to reinstall CPAN with

```
o conf init
```

in the CPAN prompt, but the outcome was the same. I am working with Perl V5.14.2 and cpanm -v brings me:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.6933 on perl 5.014002 built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
Work directory is /home/administrator/.cpanm/work/1398677790.16651
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 6.05
You have /bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.26
```

I am happy with any help, since I am a totally Linux newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BioPerl uses many modules that you might not have installed. From BioPerl INSTALL file:

> Remember that there are over 900 modules in BioPerl and the test
>   suite is running more than 12000 individual tests, a few failed tests
>   may not affect your usage of BioPerl

Most of the time you will not need these additional modules depending on what modules within BioPerl you are using. I'm sure that BioPerl has installed correctly on you system. I would work through [http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/HOWTO:Beginners](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/HOWTO%3aBeginners) to learn BioPerl. If you get errors running these basic codes in the HOWTO, repost another question.

Good luck,

Paul